# App Crash with a Null Object Reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I am using a fragment, the compiler throws no error.
But when I press the specified Button for which I created a listener, The App crashes! the logcat refers a `null object reference` to this part of the code...

```
private ImageView i;
    private String key = null;
    private ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList();

    private OnClickListener lstn = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText et1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            profilname = et1.getText().toString();


            new getPbLink().execute(new String[]{profilname});

        }

    };


    private OnClickListener lstn1 = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (pb == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"nodp", 0)
                .show();
            } else 

            { 
                SaveImage(pb);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "saved", 0)
                    .show();
            }
        }
    };
```

What to do?
logcat -

```
    Process: com.nav.drawer, PID: 21833
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.nav.drawer.HomeFragment$100000001.onClick(HomeFragment.java:61)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-22 20:43:14.696 21833 21833 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: Post your log so we can see the specific view it is referencing as null.

Comment: You seem to be inflating EditText and AutoCompleteTextView using same id: R.id.editText1. Also check the id: R.id.editText1 if it's correct

Comment: @ShahbazAhmed i've tried removing Autocomplete Textview but still it throws null object reference on editText.getText()

Comment: Please post the layout file. It seems there is no such view with id R.id.editText1

Comment: will you tell me line 61 in your HomeFragment is where in the code

Comment: Instead of calling v.findViewById(R.id.editText1) , may be you should call with view.findViewById(R.id.editText1). Here view is the inflated view from your xml layout.

Comment: I used getView(), as the method I was using was outside OnCreateView

Answer (score 7):

On an "onClick" event, the View passed is the view where you clicked. So, if you are clicking a button, you can't find any EditText because it doesn't exists here.

You need to call the function "findViewById" on the view that contains it, and not on the view passed by the method onClick.